# Getting "Procedure of function expects parameter which was not supplied" error, but all parameters are supplied

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure to add data to three tables at once. The stored procedure calls three other stored procedures. I have data for each parameter, but I keep getting a missing parameter error in SQL Server. The problem is that the parameter given in the error message isn't a part of the EXECUTE statement of the main stored procedure. Running `sp_help` shows I'm passing all the parameters needed to the main procedure. The code is below.

```sql
Error message: Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure uspAddCustomerJob, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 157]
Procedure or function 'uspAddCustomerJob' expects parameter '@intJobID', which was not supplied.
-- =========================================

-- stored procedure to add customer record to customer table

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddCustomer
     @intCustomerID AS INTEGER = 0 OUTPUT
    ,@strName AS VARCHAR(250)
    ,@strPhone AS VARCHAR(250)
    ,@strEmail AS VARCHAR(250)
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO TCustomers(strName, strPhone, strEmail)
    VALUES (@strname, @strPhone, @strEmail)

COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO

-- =================================================

-- stored procedure to add job to job table

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddJob
     @intJobID AS INTEGER = 0 OUTPUT
    ,@strJobDescription AS VARCHAR(250)
    ,@dtmStartDate AS DATETIME
    ,@dtmEndDate AS DATETIME
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO TJobs(strJobDescription, dtmStartDate, dtmEndDate)
    VALUES (@strJobDescription, @dtmStartDate, @dtmEndDate)

COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO

-- ===================================================

-- stored procedure to add PK's from previous tables to a third table (many-to-many relationship)

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddCustomerJob 
     @intCustomerJobID AS INTEGER OUTPUT
    ,@intCustomerID AS INTEGER 
    ,@intJobID AS INTEGER

AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO TCustomerJobs(intCustomerID, intJobID)
    VALUES (@intCustomerID, @intJobID)

COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO

-- =====================================================

-- main stored procedure that calls each component stored procedure, with execution code at the bottom. Running the EXECUTE statement yields the error mentioned above.

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddCustomerAndJob --main procedure 
     @intCustomerJobID      AS INTEGER  = 0 OUTPUT
    ,@strName               AS VARCHAR(250)
    ,@strPhone              AS VARCHAR(250)
    ,@strEmail              AS VARCHAR(250)
    ,@strJobDescription     AS VARCHAR(250)
    ,@dtmStartDate          AS DATETIME
    ,@dtmEndDate                AS DATETIME

AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRANSACTION

    DECLARE @intCustomerID AS INTEGER   = 0
    DECLARE @intJobID AS INTEGER            = 0

    EXECUTE uspAddCustomer @intCustomerID OUTPUT, @strName, @strPhone, @strEmail;

    EXECUTE uspAddJob @intJobID OUTPUT, @strJobDescription, @dtmStartDate, @dtmEndDate;

    EXECUTE uspAddCustomerJob @intCustomerJobID OUTPUT, @intJobID;

COMMIT TRANSACTION

GO

--TEST CODE
DECLARE @intCustomerJobID AS INTEGER;   
EXECUTE uspAddCustomerAndJob @intCustomerJobID OUTPUT, 'Joe Smith', '513-555-9644', 'Jsmith@yahoo.com', 'Fix cracked sewer pipe', '6/1/2019', '6/5/2019'
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is happening within the procedure you executed.
Procedure definition for "uspAddCustomerJob" has 3 parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddCustomerJob 
     @intCustomerJobID AS INTEGER OUTPUT
    ,@intCustomerID AS INTEGER 
    ,@intJobID AS INTEGER
```

but it is called with 2, "@intCustomerID" is missing:

```
EXECUTE uspAddCustomerJob @intCustomerJobID OUTPUT, @intJobID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is misleading. In `uspAddCustomerAndJob` you're missing a parameter.

Your call looks like this:

```
EXECUTE uspAddCustomerJob @intCustomerJobID OUTPUT, @intJobID;
```

SQL Server is taking your first integer parameter and mapping it to the first integer parameter of the child proc, so it thinks it's getting @intCustomerID.

You can avoid this sort of confusion by explicitly naming your parameters in your call, which you should do anyway for the sake of whoever (including yourself) who might need to troubleshoot the code at 3:00AM some day. So that would look like this:

```
EXECUTE uspAddCustomerJob 
  @intCustomerJobID = @intCustomerJobID OUTPUT, 
  @intCustomerID = @intCustomerID
  @intJobID = @intJobID;
```

It looks funny when your local variables are named the same thing as the parameters, but gives you the flexibility to name them differently when the situation is appropriate. Plus, no missing param surprises, or, at least, better messaging around which one is missing.